# Azure SQL DW storage cost is for used storage not max DB size?

Tags: azure-synapse

If I create a new Azure SQL DW from the portal, it starts off with a max size of 10TB (and autogrow off, I believe). If I then load only 10GB of data am I paying for 10TB of storage or only ~10GB? From what I can tell from my Azure bill, I'm only paying for 10GB (plus some for the backup snapshots which likely depend on how much data I'm changing daily, plus some for .ldf log files).

Is that accurate that you only pay for what you use and that max DB size is not involved? How does that work? If the database blobs in Azure storage were sized small initially then allowed to autogrow, I could understand only paying for what I use. But I'm unclear how I can only pay for what I use while autogrow is off and max DB size is 10TB. Can you clarify?

Edit: I believe Azure SQL DW uses page blobs. I'm wondering if the page blobs work like the page blobs used for Azure disks. If you provision a 1TB disk but only write 1GB to it, you only pay 1GB. Does that explain how you only pay for what you use in Azure SQL DW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage rates are based on standard [RA-GRS Page Blob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/) rates. You only pay for data stored, not for storage transaction fees. To be clear, you only pay for the space used not the "max size" of the DW.

Storage capacity is billed in units of the average daily amount of data stored, in gigabytes (GB), over a monthly period. For example, if you consistently utilized 10 GB of storage for the first half of the month and none for the second half of the month, you would be billed for your average usage of 5 GB of storage.

Edit: Note that since the move of SQL DW to premium storage, the pricing is a bit different. You pay for what you use in 1TB increments at the P30 premium storage rate. It doesn't appear to be related to the maxsize of your DW, just based upon what you use. You also pay for backup snapshots which is based upon how much data is changing each 8 hours. Finally geo-redundant backups if they aren't disabled are charged separately. More pricing info is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-data-warehouse/).

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I believe your answer is correct. SQL Server data files in Azure blob storage use page blobs. And I was able to confirm separately that I can create a 127GB data file in Azure but only pay for the actual data I store in that data file. Since I believe Azure SQL DW uses SQL data files in Azure blob storage, that same concept applies. Anyway, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Also, good call that you don't pay for storage transaction fees. I hadn't noticed that before.

Comment: Note that since the move of SQL DW to premium storage, the pricing is a bit different. From what I can tell, you pay for what you use in 1TB increments at the P30 premium storage rate. It doesn't appear to be related to the maxsize of your DW, just based upon what you use.

Answer (score 1):

Azure charges for actuals averaged out for a month. 
it doesn't matter if you have 1 TB  and you grow or if you have set autogrow off etc.

Hope the link below will give you more answers

Some snippets from [Microsoft site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/)

"*If I use Storage for only a few days a month, is the cost prorated? 
Yes. Storage capacity is billed in units of the average daily amount of data stored, in gigabytes (GB), over a monthly period. For example, if you consistently utilized 10 GB of storage for the first half of the month and none for the second half of the month, you would be billed for your average usage of 5 GB of storage.*"

Comment: I don't believe this answer is specific to Azure SQL DW storage. Yes, it's true that if I have a 30GB file in blob storage for the whole month, I pay for about 1GB per day. And it's true if I put a 30GB file into blob storage for one day and then delete it, the cost is prorated so I'm paying for about 1GB of storage. But this question is specific to Azure SQL DW and how they internally store data and charge you.

Comment: However, your answer did remind me of disks (page blobs) in standard storage. If you provision a 1TB disk but only write 1GB to it, you only pay 1GB. Let me edit my question to see if this is how SQL data files in blob storage used by Azure SQL DW work, too.

Comment: have you seen this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-overview-what-is/)

Comment: This documentation page also has details of how the Azure DBW works and

Comment: But we have to remember that at the end of the day this is just a clustered sql server, and since we are paying for the service this cluster is providing we are paying for actuals used (this includes a part of infra cost) and not the actual server and software's completly.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the architecture. Just asking a specific question about how storage is charged and confirming you only pay for what you use not for the max DB size. I don't believe you have answered that.

Comment: hmm let me dig deeper and get back to you. even I will have to do a bit more research